# How to plot sjPlots from a nested tibble?

Tags: r, tidyr, sjplot

I create some models like this using a nested tidyr dataframe:

```
set.seed(1)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(sjPlot)
library(tibble)
library(purrr)

fits <- tribble(~group, ~colA, ~colB, ~colC,
        sample(c("group1", "group2"), 10, replace = T), 0, sample(10, replace = T), sample(10, replace = T),
        sample(c("group1", "group2"), 10, replace = T), 1, sample(10, replace = T), sample(10, replace = T)) %>% 
    unnest(cols = c(colB, colC)) %>%
    nest(data=-group) %>%
    mutate(fit= map(data, ~glm(formula = colA ~ colB + colC, data = .x, family="binomial"))) %>%
    dplyr::select(group, fit) %>%
    tibble::column_to_rownames("group")
```

I would like to use this data to create some quick marginal effects plots with `sjPlot::plot_models` like this

```
plot_models(as.list(fits), type = "pred", terms = c("colB", "colA", "colC"))
```

Unfortunately, I get the error

```
Error in if (fam.info$is_linear) tf <- NULL else tf <- "exp" : 
  argument is of length zero
In addition: Warning message:
Could not access model information.
```

I've played around a bit with the nesting of the data but I've been unable to get it into a format that `sjPlot::plot_models` will accept.

What I was expecting to get is a "Forest plot of multiple regression models" as described in the help file. Ultimately, the goal is to plot the marginal effects of regression models by group, which I was hoping the plot_models will do (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Your example code to generate `fits` gives "Error: Can't find column `rowname` in `.data`" ?

Comment: It should work now, forgot to specify the group.

Comment: @TeaTree Please try to edit your question or even answer your question as I think I am getting something similar and I am interested to know the answer.Upvoted. Thx

Comment: I added the purrr package to the code, which I had forgotten earlier. I'm not sure what you mean @MohamedRahouma. I don't know the answer to my problem but the MWE should work now.

Comment: Think I might be getting somewhere with `unnest(cols = group)` in place of `column_to_rownames(group)` - the latter is using the list elements as rownames, whereas the prior unlists the vectors. Also getting something from subsequent `mutate(models = map(fit, plot_models))` - I can't see your additional arguments in the documentation. That's doing something, but definitely not what it's supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

It think there are some issues with the original code as well as with the data. There are arguments from `plot_model` in the function call which are not supported in `plot_models`. I first show an example that shows how `plot_models` can be called and used with a nested `tibble` using {ggplot2}'s `diamonds` data set. Then I apply this approach to the OP's sample data, which doesn't yield useable results*. Finally, I create some new toy data to show how the approach could be applied to a binominal model.

(* In the original toy data the dependent variable is either always `0` or always `1` in each model so this is unlikely to yield useable results).

```r
set.seed(1)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(sjPlot)
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)

# general example
fits <- tibble(id = c("x", "y", "z")) %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(fit = list(glm(reformulate(
    termlabels = c("cut", "color", "depth", "table", "price", id),
    response = "carat"),
    data = diamonds)))

plot_models(fits$fit)
```

[image]

```r
# OP's example data
fits2 <- tribble(~group, ~colA, ~colB, ~colC,
                 sample(c("group1", "group2"), 10, replace = T), 0,
                 sample(10, replace = T), sample(10, replace = T),
                 sample(c("group1", "group2"), 10, replace = T), 1,
                 sample(10, replace = T),
                 sample(10, replace = T)) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(colB, colC)) %>%
  nest(data = -group) %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(fit = list(glm(formula = colA ~ colB + colC, data = data, family="binomial")))

plot_models(fits2$fit)
#> Warning: Transformation introduced infinite values in continuous y-axis
#> Warning: Removed 4 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image]

```r
# new data for binominal model
n <- 500
g <- round(runif(n, 0L, 1L), 0)
x1 <- runif(n,0,100)
x2 <- runif(n,0,100)
y <- (x2 - x1 + rnorm(n,sd=20)) < 0

fits3 <- tibble(g, y, x1, x2) %>% 
  nest_by(g) %>% 
  mutate(fit = list(glm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2, data = data, family="binomial")))

plot_models(fits3$fit)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>